# Setting 'selected' option for select element in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have an array- `selected_players`, which I am looping through in Vue.js, but am not able to set the `selected` attribute of an `option`.

What I am trying: `:selected="player.round.best_player == 1"`

Here is the section of the related template:

```
    <div v-if="selected_players.length && ! loading">
        <h4>Select Best Player</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="best-player" id="best-player" v-model="best_player" class="form-control">
                <option v-for="player in selected_players" :value="player.id" :selected="player.round.best_player == 1">{{ player.name }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br />
```

When loaded, this is the related HTML:

```
<select name="best-player" id="best-player" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Ashley</option>
</select>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What happens when you change your `selected="player.round.best_player == 1"` statement as `selected="{{player.round.best_player == 1}}"` ?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but from memory, Vue.js 2.x only allows setting properties programmatically via binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a selected option, you can just set the `best_player` as the one you want to have by default selected.

With below code I am iterating over your `player` array and finding the player which has `round.best_player === 1`. The idea is to set the `best_player` with the selected option.

```
best_player = player.filter(p => p.round.best_player === 1).id
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the fix :)